# Problem while passing binded list of objects in Spring 5

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, jsp

Good Morning,
I am developing a system which can accept multiple object at the same time, technology used are:

- Spring 5.2.5.RELEASE For the backend,
- Jsp for Front layer.

The main goal is to let the user put 16 (predefined number, so it is not dynamic the lenght of the array) records of a "Delta P" data with only one form.
As the "nome_operatore" and "data_operazione_delta_p" are equal in all the records, they are submitted only ones and then replicated in the controller for all records submitted.

Since now I came out with the subsequent classes following various tutorials here on SO and over the net.

In general, the view is correctly displayed (I scanned the code generated by Spring and it is correct as far as I know) and the `GetMapping` to display the form page works correctly as well (I debugged to see if some data were not correct, but I found no errors).
The only problem is that when I submit the form, the page freezes and after a while Chrome display an advise saying that is impossibile to load the page.
The server is still running, as the server keeps logging correctly, but the line

```
    logger.info("submitted form to create multiple Delta P data");
```

is never reached.
No errors are displayed either in Chrome console.

If this is not the correct way to upload multiple items at one time, how this could be done in Spring 5?

**EDIT**

After investigation I found chrome giving a `RESULT_CODE_HUNG` error, but on the net I found nothing useful to fix it, only people complaining about "chrome killing pages", can someone explain what this error means at least? I tried to document myself but with no success. The same error shows up also in Edge and Firefox.

**List wrapper**

```
package com.entsorgafin.dto;

import com.entsorgafin.model.Dato_delta_p;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeltaPListWrapper
{
    private List<Dato_delta_p> deltaPList;
    
    public DeltaPListWrapper()
    {
        this.deltaPList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    
    public List<Dato_delta_p> getDeltaPList()
    {
        return deltaPList;
    }
    
    public void setDeltaPList(List<Dato_delta_p> deltaPList)
    {
        this.deltaPList = deltaPList;
    }
    
    public void add(Dato_delta_p dato_delta_p)
    {
        this.deltaPList.add(dato_delta_p);
    }
}
```

**Controller methods**

```
/**
 * Shows the form to insert a new delta p data series in the system.
 * <p>
 * Returns the form page.
 *
 * @param model ModelMap of the UI
 * @return The form page to insert one record for each sector
 */
@GetMapping("/addDeltaP")
public String addDeltaP(ModelMap model)
{
    logger.info("adding Delta P data");
    
    logger.debug("finding infos for front end representation");
    //finding users to relate the records with
    List<Utente> users = utentiService.findAllUsers();
    logger.debug("found " + users.size() + " users");
    Map<Integer, String> userForFE = new HashMap<>();
    for(Utente utente : users)
    {
        userForFE.put(utente.getId_utente(), utente.getNome() + " " + utente.getCognome());
    }
    model.addAttribute("users", userForFE);
    
    //finding active sectors
    List<Settore> activeSectors = new ArrayList<>();
    activeSectors.addAll(settoriService.findActiveSectorForPhase("act"));
    activeSectors.addAll(settoriService.findActiveSectorForPhase("cur"));
    logger.debug("found " + activeSectors.size() + " active sectors");
    
    //creating wrapper which contains multiple Delta P records
    DeltaPListWrapper listWrapper = new DeltaPListWrapper();
    
    //Pre-filling sector field for delta P data
    for(Settore sect : activeSectors)
    {
        Dato_delta_p dato_delta_p = new Dato_delta_p();
        dato_delta_p.setSettore(sect);
        listWrapper.add(dato_delta_p);
    }
    model.addAttribute("deltaPData", listWrapper);
    model.addAttribute("activeSectorNumber", activeSectors.size());
    
    return "uploadDeltaPData";
}

/**
 * Saves a new series of data record in the database.
 *
 * @param listWrapper List of Delta p data to create
 * @return Returns the homepage
 */
@PostMapping("/addDeltaP")
public String addDeltaP(@ModelAttribute("deltaPData") DeltaPListWrapper listWrapper)
{
    logger.info("submitted form to create multiple Delta P data");
    
    /*
    getting Date of the first record, operations are performed on the same date, so
    every record will have the same property for data_operazione
    
    The same stands for the user who performed the operations
     */
    LocalDate dataOperazione = listWrapper.getDeltaPList().get(0).getData_operazione_delta_p();
    Utente idUtente = listWrapper.getDeltaPList().get(0).getUtente_id_utente();
    
    /*
    Filling delta P data with active batch for the sector they are from
     */
    for(Dato_delta_p dato_delta_p : listWrapper.getDeltaPList())
    {
        dato_delta_p.setUtente_id_utente(idUtente);
        dato_delta_p.setData_operazione_delta_p(dataOperazione);
        
        String phase;
        Settore used = settoriService.findSectorById(dato_delta_p.getSettore().getId_settore());
        if(used.getFase().equals("act"))
        {
            phase = "act";
        } else
        {
            phase = "cur";
        }
        
        Lotto referencedLotto = lottoService
                .findActiveBatchInSectorAndDate(dato_delta_p.getData_operazione_delta_p(), dato_delta_p
                        .getSettore(), phase);
        logger.debug("found Lotto with ID " + referencedLotto.getId_lotto() + " for Delta P record");
        dato_delta_p.setLotto_id_lotto(referencedLotto);
        
        //creating the data
        dati_delta_pService.createDeltaPData(dato_delta_p);
        logger.info("Delta P data created correctly");
    }
    
    return "redirect:/entsorgafin/home";
}
```

**JSP view**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Inserisci i dati delta P</h1>

    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="deltaPData" onsubmit="enableFields(${activeSectorNumber})">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="utente_id_utente">Nome dell'operatore</label>
                <form:select class="form-control" id="utente_id_utente" path="${deltaPList[0].utente_id_utente.id_utente}" required="required">
                    <form:option value="" />
                    <form:options items="${users}" />
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="data_operazione_delta_p">Data dell'operazione</label>
                <form:input path="${deltaPList[0].data_operazione_delta_p}" type="date" class="form-control" id="data_operazione_delta_p" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col my-auto">Numero del settore</div>
            <div class="col my-auto">Valore deltaP rilevato</div>
            <div class="col my-auto">Velocità ventilatore</div>
            <div class="col my-auto">Settore pieno</div>
            <div class="col my-auto">Settore in caricamento</div>
        </div>
        <c:forEach items="${deltaPData.deltaPList}" varStatus="i">
            <form:input path="deltaPList[${i.index}].id_dato_delta_p" type="hidden" id="id_dati_delta_p" />

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <form:input path="deltaPList[${i.index}].settore.id_settore" class="form-control text-center" id="settore${i.index}" required="required" disabled="true"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <form:input path="deltaPList[${i.index}].valore_delta_p" type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="valore_delta_p" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <form:input path="deltaPList[${i.index}].velocita_ventilatore" type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="velocita_ventilatore" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col my-auto">
                    <form:checkbox path="deltaPList[${i.index}].stato_settore_pieno" id="stato_settore_pieno${i.index}" value="true" onclick="disableSettoreCaricoBox(${i.index})"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col my-auto">
                    <form:checkbox path="deltaPList[${i.index}].stato_settore_carico" id="stato_settore_carico${i.index}" value="true" onclick="disableSettorePienoBox(${i.index})"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>

        <input type="submit" value="create" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

    </form:form>
</div>

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>

<script>
    function disableSettoreCaricoBox(i)
    {
        const checked = document.getElementById('stato_settore_pieno' + i).checked;

        document.getElementById("stato_settore_carico" + i).disabled = !!checked;
    }
    function disableSettorePienoBox(i)
    {
        const checked = document.getElementById('stato_settore_carico' + i).checked;

        document.getElementById("stato_settore_pieno" + i).disabled = !!checked;
    }
    function enableFields(i)
    {
        for(let x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            document.getElementById("settore" + x).disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually feel kind of an idiot for not noticing it before, after focusing on Spring possible errors I lost a minor point in the code where the error actually is: Javascript function.

```
function enableFields(i)
{
    for(let x = 0; x < i; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("settore" + x).disabled = false;
    }
}
```

should be

```
function enableFields(i)
{
    for(let x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        document.getElementById("settore" + x).disabled = false;
    }
}
```

I'll correct the quetion code, hope this could anyway help someone who's searching an example of multi row submitting in Spring 5.